# Cannot use supervisor with Apache Kafka

Tags: ubuntu, supervisord, ubuntu-16.04, kafka

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 machine where Apache Kafka is installed. Currently, I can make it work flawlessly by using a `start_kafka.sh` script with the following contents:

```
JMX_PORT=17264 KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xms1024M -Xmx3072M" /home/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon /home/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/config/server.properties
```

Now, I want to use `supervisor` to automatically restart the process should it fail and start immediately after rebooting the machine. The problem is that I cannot make `supervisor` start Kafka.

I installed `supervisor` using `pip` and placed this configuration file at `/etc/supervisord.conf`:

```
; Supervisor config file.
;
; For more information on the config file, please see:
; http://supervisord.org/configuration.html

[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)

[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[program:kafka]
command=/home/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/start_kafka.sh ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
;process_name=%(program_name)s ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
startsecs=10                   ; # of secs prog must stay up to be running (def. 1)
startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures when starting (default 3)
;autorestart=unexpected        ; when to restart if exited after running (def: unexpected)
;exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes used with autorestart (default 0,2)
stopsignal=TERM               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
stopwaitsecs=180               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
stdout_logfile=NONE        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
;environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions (def no adds)
```

When I try to start Kafka, the following error occurs:

```
# supervisorctl start kafka
kafka: ERROR (spawn error)
```

And the supervisor log (at `/tmp/supervisord.log`) contains this:

```
2017-01-23 22:10:24,532 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 21311
2017-01-23 22:10:24,536 INFO exited: kafka (exit status 127; not expected)
2017-01-23 22:10:25,542 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 21312
2017-01-23 22:10:25,559 INFO exited: kafka (exit status 127; not expected)
2017-01-23 22:10:27,562 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 21313
2017-01-23 22:10:27,567 INFO exited: kafka (exit status 127; not expected)
2017-01-23 22:10:30,571 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 21314
2017-01-23 22:10:30,576 INFO exited: kafka (exit status 127; not expected)
2017-01-23 22:10:31,578 INFO gave up: kafka entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

It must be said that I've already tried removing the `-daemon` flag in `start_kafka.sh` to use with `supervisor` but without success.

Does anyone have an idea on what's going on?

Comment: Why are you trying to use supervisor for this? You should just make a normal systemd unit.

Comment: AFAIK systemd can auto-initialize my process when I start up the machine, but I'm not sure whether it can auto-restart in case the process crashes. Does it have this feature?

Comment: Of course it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get supervisor working with Kafka with two changes:

- Deploy Kafka without `-daemon` flag, as supervisor requires non-daemozined process to manage
- Explicitly define the Java path in supervisor configuration file

This is the working configuration:

start_kafka.sh

```
JMX_PORT=17264 KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xms1024M -Xmx3072M" /home/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /home/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/config/server.properties
```

supervisord.conf

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf

[program:kafka]
command=/home/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/start_kafka.sh
directory=/home/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/kafka/stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/kafka/stderr.log
environment = JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```